# update ui from background thread Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to update UI from onPostExecute method in may async task. What I am trying is I am parsing an xml and take texts from there.. I need to create textView dynamically from onPostExecute() for each xml node it contain text and add it to my layout..

when I try to do this a got NetworkOnMainThreadException..

me tried handler to solve this issue, but didn't get working properly.

please check my code.

```
protected void onPostExecute(final InputStream stream) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
    pDialog.dismiss();

      try {

          XmlPullParser xpp = Xml.newPullParser();
          xpp.setInput(stream, null);
            xpp.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            xpp.next();
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            System.out.println("eventType : " + eventType);

              String tagname = null;
              String type = null;
              String link = null;
              String content = null;

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {

                 if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT){
                    // str += "\nXML Parsing Starting...\n";
                     eventType = xpp.next();
                     continue;
                 }
                 else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                 {
                    // str +=  "\nroot tag: "+xpp.getName();
                     tagname = xpp.getName();

                     if(xpp.getName().equals("text")){
                         if(xpp.getAttributeCount()>0){
                             type = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "type");
                            // str +=  "\nroot attr: "+type;
                         }

                     }
                     else if((xpp.getName().equals("image")) || (xpp.getName().equals("audio")) || (xpp.getName().equals("video")) ){
                         if(xpp.getAttributeCount()>0){
                             link = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "src");
                            // str +=  "\nroot attr: "+link;
                         }
                     }
                 }

                 else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                 {
                     content = xpp.getText();
                    // str += "\nvalue : "+xpp.getText();
                 }
                 else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
                 {
                    // str += "\nending tag: "+xpp.getName();


                     eventType = xpp.next();
                     continue;
                 }
                 System.out.println("content : " + content);
                 System.out.println("tagname : " + tagname);

                 if(content != null ){
                 if((tagname.equals("text") || tagname.equals("preview")) ){

                     // UPDATE_TEXT =1;
                     // TextView text = new TextView(ContentView.this);
                     text = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                     text.setText(content);

                     if(type != null){
                         if(type.equals("heading1"))
                             text.setTextAppearance(ContentView.this, R.style.heading1);
                         else if(type.equals("heading2"))
                             text.setTextAppearance(ContentView.this, R.style.heading2);
                         else if(type.equals("heading3"))
                             text.setTextAppearance(ContentView.this, R.style.heading3);
                         else if(type.equals("heading4"))
                             text.setTextAppearance(ContentView.this, R.style.heading4);
                         type = null;
                     }
                     if (text != null && layout != null){
                         Log.e(getPackageName(), text.toString());

                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                 Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
                                 message.what = 1;
                                 handler.sendMessage(message);
                                 // handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                                 // layout.addView(text);
                             }
                         });
                     }

                     content = null;
                 }
                 else if((tagname.equals("image"))){

                     text = new TextView(ContentView.this);
                     text.setText(content);

                     if(link != null){

                         link = null;
                     }
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                             handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    // layout.addView(text);
                         }
                     });
                     content = null;
                 }
                 }

                 eventType = xpp.next();
            }
            // str += "\n\nXML parsing Ending......";

      } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

check my handler class in activity class..

```
protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1:
            layout.addView(text);

            break;
        case 2:
            layout.addView(text);
            break;
        }
    }
  };
```

still am getting same error.

Comment: When it throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, it means do your work in separate thread. Thus, create new thread and do your work using it. This exception is thrown when you try to do some task that may take long time such as getting some data from web.

Answer (score 0):

you need Object Model for data infos and setter and can used this:

```
private ProgressDialog progressBar;

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
    progressBar.setMessage("please, waiting ...");
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar.show();

 }

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {

        // parsing xml and get data 
        // get info and set them in my model ...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return params[0];
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (null != progressBar && progressBar.isShowing()) {
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }

    // do work in UI and set getter informations and set layout ...
   switch(select) {
   case 1:
        layout.addView(text);

        break;
    case 2:
        layout.addView(text);
        break;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.. am not familiar to model class building.. can u give me some code.. i mean the getter n setter class.. i can parse the xml in my doInBackground() but dont know how to update my ui each time after a node parse complete.. ie, when we got the first content and its type and attribute, i need to update the ui accroding to that.. that part make me confused..

Answer (score 0):

You failed to post the entire `AsyncTask`, forcing everyone to have to guess.

My guess is that you did the HTTP connection in `doInBackground()`, then passed the resulting `InputStream` to `onPostExecute()`. This will not work, as that `InputStream` is tied to a network socket.

Move your `InputStream` and XML parsing into `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply..Yes its was done like that. I think that is the problem, but don't know how to implement it. i can parse the xml in my doInBackground() but dont know how to update my ui each time after a node parse complete.. ie, when we got the first content and its type and attribute, i need to update the ui accroding to that.. that part make me confused..

Comment: @VivekPPillai: "dont know how to update my ui each time after a node parse complete" -- store the interim results generated by `doInBackground()` in an object of your own design. Return that object from `doInBackground()`, which then supplies that object as a parameter to `onPostExecute()`. Update the UI in `onPostExecute()` based upon the data in your parse-results object.

Comment: hi i have moved the xml parsing section to the doInBackground() method.. there each nodes are parsing when we reach and get a text node and its attribute, what i actually need is , i need to create a dynamic textview in iu with text node content.. when an image node come i need to add an imageview to the ui and so on. format of xml is not static it will be different at each time and the order of image and text node will be diff at times. i need a solution for this.. please help me. how can we solve it with object , could you please provide me some codes.